# Serializing an array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, form-submit, form-serialize

How to prepare an array of element for `$.ajax` submit?

Here images return `["val1","val2"]`, but after I use `$.param(images)` I get the following:

> undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined

Here is my code:

```
$('#rem_images').click(function() {
    var images = new Array();
    $('.images_set_image input:checked').each(function(i) {
        images[i] = $(this).val();
    });
    alert($.param(images));

    return false;
}
```

Generally the idea is to check the images to delete on the page, then on a button click loop trough all images checked and serialize an array for submit over AJAX to the PHP script.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're not passing an array in proper format to `$.param`. From the [`jQuery.param` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

> If the object passed is in an Array, it must be an array of objects in the format returned by [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

The array should be an array of objects consisting of name/value pairs. You see `undefined=undefined&undefined=undefined` because `"val1".name`, `"val1".value`, `"val2".name`, and `"val2".value`, are all undefined. It should look something like this:

```
[{name: 'name1', value: 'val1'}, {name: 'name2', value: 'val2'}]
```

So you can construct the array like this (assuming your checkboxes have a `name` attribute):

```
$('#rem_images').click(function(){
    var images = [];
    $('.images_set_image input:checked').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        images.push({name: $this.attr('name'), value: $this.val()});
    });
    alert($.param(images));
    return false;
});
```

Even slicker, though, is to use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) (because functional programming is good stuff):

```
$('#rem_images').click(function(){
    var images = $('.images_set_image input:checked').map(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        return {name: $this.attr('name'), value: $this.val()};
    }).get();
    alert($.param(images));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This matter was difficult for me to understand, but with your answer and some investigation I've managed to do what I wanted, THANK YOU =)

Answer (score 8):

See the [docs for `$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

> If the object passed is in an Array, it must be an array of objects in the format returned by .serializeArray()

```
[{name:"first",value:"Rick"},
{name:"last",value:"Astley"},
{name:"job",value:"Rock Star"}]
```

That means you need to generate your array in the same way:

```
$('.images_set_image input:checked').each(function(i){
    images.push({ name: i, value: $(this).val() });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I find a great function to do that from another question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31751351/4110122

This function return array with key value pairs

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }      
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

To use this just call:

```
var Form_Data = $('form').serializeObject();
console.log(Form_Data);
```