# Pass array to ajax request in $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I want to send an array as an Ajax request:

```
info[0] = 'hi';
info[1] = 'hello';

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "index.php",
  success: function(msg){
    $('.answer').html(msg);
  }
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713884/convert-js-array-to-json-object-for-use-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: type: 'POST',
    url: '/url/action/',
    data: { param1: 1, id: "text" },
    dataType: 'text',

Answer (score 283, accepted):

```
info = [];
info[0] = 'hi';
info[1] = 'hello';


$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {info:info},
   url: "index.php",
   success: function(msg){
     $('.answer').html(msg);
   }
});
```

Comment: yes...that worked..thanks..one more thing can be done ...that is initialize **info = {};** then **data: info,**

Comment: it sends 0=hi&1=hello, will it work ? depends on your server side code. info = {} is a plain object in Javascript. info = [] is an array object.

Comment: How would you do it if you want `info=arrayasvalues` instead of every key is a param?

Comment: do you mean info=0,1 ?

Comment: I am doing this, with my C# controller having both a `List<string>` and a `string[]` parameter, but in both cases, the array being past ends up being one comma-delimited string in the first element of the `List<string>` or `string[]` param.  Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 77):

Just use the JSON.stringify method and pass it through as the "data" parameter for the $.ajax function, like follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ paramName: info }),
    success: function(msg){
        $('.answer').html(msg);
    }
});
```

You just need to make sure you include the JSON2.js file in your page...

Comment: I needed to add `JSON.stringify(...)` Thanks for the assist!

Comment: In my case, requested key-value map was wrong with above code. I changed "data" line to: data: { paramName: JSON.stringify(info)},

Comment: I tried this, with my C# controller having both a `List<string>` and a `string[]` parameter, but in both cases, the array being past ends up being one comma-delimited string in the first element of the `List<string>` or `string[]` param.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Joe Try specifying dataType in the $.ajax call as "application/json". If you're using Web API, make sure to decorate the the parameter to your controller with the [FromBody] attribute so it can be deserialized correctly.

Comment: In C#, its need to be deserialized      JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[]> (params)

Answer (score -3):

**NOTE**: Doesn't work on newer versions of jQuery.

Since you are using jQuery please use it's seralize function to serialize data and then pass it into the data parameter of ajax call:

```
info[0] = 'hi';
info[1] = 'hello';

var data_to_send = $.serialize(info);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: data_to_send,
    success: function(msg){
        $('.answer').html(msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not the whole true, at least not today. jQuery wouldn't actually auto-serialize just any array. When I tried with simple array of integers, it kept just the last item. Please, check this post for more explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4239496/261332

Comment: Thank you @userfuser

I have updated the answer and removed the auto serialize part.

Comment: how does this have so many upvotes?  There is no such jQuery function as `jQuery.serialize()`.  There is `.serialize()` but it's meant to be used on a set of form elements.  Try this code and you will only get `TypeError: $.serialize is not a function`

Comment: How does even this work for you?

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar see the answer date?

Comment: @BlackDivine So this was working until 2012?

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar yes and quite a bit after that, if you find a recent uptodate way please update answer and I will accept the edit.

Comment: @BlackDivine [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) could be used, so something like `$.param({info: info})` would achieve the same result.

Comment: this is not working at all.

Comment: @GautamRai perhaps you can suggest an edit?

Comment: This answer is wrong, There is no such possibilities