# Array size is always 1 in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a function which gets the value of each checked checkbox i was able to get the value successfully by using an alert example it results to `1,2,3` which is correct but when i get it from php the array size is always 1.

HTML CODE:

```
function doit() {
    var p = [];
    $('input.cb').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            p.push($(this).attr('rel'));
        }
    });
    $.ajax( {
          url:'page.php',
          type:'POST',
          data: {list:p},
          success: function(res) {
               alert(res);
          }
    });
    alert(p)
}
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
  $list = $_POST['list'];
  echo count($list);
?>
```

Comment: Pl provide HTML code also ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass array to ajax request in $.ajax()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code :

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(p);

$.ajax( {
      url:'page.php',
      type:'POST',
      data: {list:jsonData},
      success: function(res) {
             alert(res);
      }
});
```

And in PHP :

```
$list = json_decode($_POST['list']);
```