# How I can post JavaScript array to Laravel's Controller using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I had an array like the following

```
var a = [
        {
            "start":"2015-01-12T00:00:00.000Z",
            "allDay":false,
            "promotion_option":"banner"
        },
        {
            "start":"2015-01-13T00:00:00.000Z",
            "allDay":false,
            "promotion_option":"banner"
        }
    ];
```

And I post that object of array like the following using JQuery Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: url,
    data: a,
    success: function(res) {
        var message = res.mesg;

        if (message) {
            $('.flash').html(message).fadeIn(300).delay(250).fadeOut(300);
        };
    }
});
```

In my controller when I try `dd(Input::all())`, it's just return

```
array(1) {
  ["undefined"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

So, How I can get the value of what I had posted?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax look here, maybe, adding `{...}` for data will help

Comment: send an object like this: `{a:a}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass data as Object and use `dataType:'json'` as you are using `res.mesg` in success callback like this,

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: url,
    data: {a:a},//<== use object here
    dataType:'json',// add this, as you are using res.mesg
    success: function(res) {
        var message = res.mesg;
        if (message) {
            $('.flash').html(message).fadeIn(300).delay(250).fadeOut(300);
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try `JSON.stringify(a)` which will convert it to something like this

```
"[{"start":"2015-01-12T00:00:00.000Z","allDay":false,"promotion_option":"banner"},{"start":"2015-01-13T00:00:00.000Z","allDay":false,"promotion_option":"banner"}]"
```

Note that it converts it into a string in your backend whereever you recieve the httprequest you just have to keep that in mind.Hope it helps