# How to write AJAX request which contains two pieces of POST data?

Tags: javascript, ajax

So basically I'm trying to send WebGL frames/screenshots to a server which may save these frames to the hard drive so I'll be able to merge these saved frames to video file.
I have found this:
[Exporting video from webgl](http://www.oampo.co.uk/2011/01/exporting-video-from-webgl/)

I don't like to bother you guys with the WebGL related details... The only thing you should know that I would like to send the content of two client side JavaScript variables to the localhost node.js server. So these two client side variables are the following:

```
            var frame = frame + 1; //this is the frame counter
            var dataUrl = renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/png"); //this is the encoded screenshot/frame
```

the receiver server side code is given by Joe Turner (this is running in node.js).
So my question is: how to send the above mentioned two variable's content to this node.js code?

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var fs = require('fs');

// Override so we don't decode spaces, and mess up the base64 encoding
querystring.unescape = function(s, decodeSpaces) {
    return s;
};

// Pad to follow the processing export format
function pad(num) {
    var s = "000" + num;
    return s.substr(s.length-4);
}

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.content = '';
    request.addListener("data", function(data) {
        request.content += data;
    });

    request.addListener("end", function() {
        if (request.content.trim()) {
            request.content = querystring.parse(request.content);
            var data = unescape(request.content['data']);
            var frame = request.content['frame'];
            // Remove data:image/png;base64,
            data = data.substr(data.indexOf(',') + 1);
            var buffer = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
            fs.writeFile('screen-' + pad(frame) + '.png',
                         buffer.toString('binary'), 'binary');
        }
    });
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With'
    });
    response.end();
}).listen(8080, "127.0.0.1");
```

Should I do something like this?

```
            ...
            ...
            //WebGL related code
            ...
            ...
                            var frame = frame + 1;
                            var dataUrl = renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/png");

                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: {"data": dataUrl, "frame": frame}

                                });
            ...
            ...
```

For example let's see this experiment:

[Three.js basic example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_collada_keyframe)

I changed this piece of code in the above experiment:

```
        pointLight.position.copy( camera.position );

        progress += frameTime;
        lastTimestamp = timestamp;
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
        stats.update();
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
```

To this:

```
        pointLight.position.copy( camera.position );

        progress += frameTime;
        lastTimestamp = timestamp;
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
        stats.update();
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        var dataUrl = "data:image/png;base64,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";
        var frame = 10;

        $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
                type: "POST",
                data: {"data": dataUrl, "frame": frame}    
        });
```

But still cannot see any saved image file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass array to ajax request in $.ajax()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote only needs to have the correct protocol in its url (you were missing "**http://**") :

```
var frame = frame + 1;
var dataUrl = renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/png");

$.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"data": dataUrl, "frame": frame}    
});
```

From the code you posted, you can see the server is already parsing the request and extracting the two parameters you send in POST

```
if (request.content.trim()) {    
    request.content = querystring.parse(request.content);
    var data = request.content['data'];
    var frame = request.content['frame'];
    //...
```

Anything you add to the POST request in $.ajax can be retrieved by name when calling

```
request.content['name']
```

Just make sure the names you use in the client and server code match.

Also, the node.js code is receiving an escaped base64 string, which doesn't make this function work

```
data.substr(data.indexOf(',') + 1);
```

Since the ',' character is escaped.

To solve this just use the node built-in function **unescape** on the data string like this

```
var data = unescape(request.content['data']);
```

Comment: It's fine, corrected my code, but node.js still not displaying anything or does not save any picture. Where should the pictures to be saved by node.js?

Comment: I updated my answer, after unescaping the data variable the server saves images correctly. The pictures get saved in the directory where you **execute** node.js. If you want to use a specific directory just add it before the filename `fs.writeFile(directoryPath + 'screen-' + pad(frame) + '.png', ...)`

Comment: Made these changes you suggested, but still no image on the directory path I've specified. I'm a newcomer to node.js. So just please doublecheck how to start the node.js with the script above. I copied and pasted the above node.js related code into a text file (xy.txt), then went to cmd (where xy.txt takes place) and typed "node xy.txt".
I only see a black screen. No image created.

Comment: That's correct, you don't see any output on the server. After you start it with cmd you need to execute `$.ajax` from your javascript and send the parameters **while the server is still running**. 
If you're unsure try this [snippet](http://pastebin.com/2EsSuket) I was using to test your code right from your browser developer's console, it requires jquery, of course.

Comment: Please see: I've updated my original question. Unescaped the node.js code, tested all your codes. Ran a native three.js example with your code included meanwhile the node.js code was running.
Still no saved image.
May I ask you please to download the three.js experiment I just linked in my original question and implement the AJAX part into it?
May I ask you please to give it a try on your side?