# How to get form data to servlet in array list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    User Name:<input type="text" name="user" id="user"/>
    Password <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"/>
    Phone <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone"/>
    Email <input type="email" name="email" id="email"/>
    State <input type="text" name="state" id="text"/>
    <input type="button"  onclick="return register();" value="submit"/><br/>
    <div id="welcometext"></div>
</form>
```

```js
function register() { 
    var val = $('#form1 :input').serialize*();
    $.post('ActionServlet', { data: val }, function (responseText) {
        $('#welcometext').text(responseText);
    });       
}
```

Now i want to get this data in Servlet and add to mysql database and fetch data and response that data to the form in div tag. Please help me.

Comment: use $.post to send data to server.

Comment: Your usage of `$.param` is very strange (and incorrectly used) in this case. I think you want `serialize()` instead

Comment: Look at following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax

Comment: I agree, you should definitely use `var val = $('#form1 :input').serialize();`. Also, why are you using `decodeURIComponent`? You are about to send data to the backend, so eventually it should be `encodeURIComponent`, but it's unnecessary because of `.serialize()`

Comment: thanks for all suggestions hope code is now in well form

Comment: Sorry about the * typo, it's `.serialize()`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using spring controller, but hope this snippet will be helpful for you

```
var formFields = {
            "user" : $("#user").val(),
            "password" :$("#pass").val(),
             //.... other fields
 }

function register() { 
    $.post('ActionServlet', { data: formFields}, function (responseText) {
        $('#welcometext').text(responseText);
    });       
}
```

Servlet

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ActionServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public String getData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
      String name = request.getParameter("parameter you want to retrive");
    return "response you want to send";
  }
```

**NOTE:** You form has a field password, if you are using ajax to send this data , password which is a secure identity will be visible in request . So it is better to use form `submit` rather than using ajax to submit the form

Comment: i want to retrieve all  & sir i am using servlet jsp not spring frame work but its i got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery ajaxForm http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

```
$('#form1').ajaxForm(function(response){
  //response from server
});
```