# how can i send a dict in data of ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, frontend

```
data: {
    'data_params': data_params,
    'template_name': template_name,
    'channels': channels,
    'address': address,
    'task_name': task_name
}
```

address is like:

```
address -> { "links": '["abc","pqr"]' }
```

I have tried doing it like

```
 var address = {'links':links};
```

but in post request it shows something like this:

```
'address[links]': [u'["abc","pqr"]']
```

Comment: can you share some working code on jsfiddle to help us to understand better?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax

Comment: if this is javascript, you have syntax error in data: data : {} should be data ={}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is listed as a string not an array. therefore address["links"] is pointing to a string.

should be:
address = { links: ["a","b"]}