# Get JQUERY function return in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, return

I want to know if I can get the return of a JQUERY function, in PHP ?

I have this following jquery function, returning an array and I want to get this array in my PHP, in order to send it to process the data

```
function getItemMetaList() {
        var itemMetaArray = [];
        $('.frm_pro_form input, .frm_pro_form select, .frm_pro_form textarea').each(function(cpt){
            if($(this).attr('type') != 'hidden' && ($(this).attr("type") != "submit")) {
                console.log(cpt);
                console.log($(this).attr("name"));
                itemMetaArray.push($(this).attr("name"));
            }
        });
        return itemMetaArray;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Either use AJAX or put value in a hidden input and submit the form

Comment: The problem with AJAX is that normally you use it with PHP functions right ? I don't see how I can send JQUERY data to my PHP file with AJAX. For the input method I can't do that, I have to get the JQUERY array with a button click in my php page

Comment: you can send your javascript* array with ajax called in jquery like in documentation without php function

Comment: Yeah I finally find it. I just have a problem. I send an array, but I didn't get an array in PHP, just the content of the array. Any solutions for this ?

Comment: what do you mean by the "just the content" $_POST isn't an array ?

Comment: I mean : My array looks like this : Array [ "item_meta[71]", "item_meta[65]", "item_meta[70]", "item_meta[66]", "file67" ]
How can I get the same result in my PHP page ? While I'm using (var_dump($_POST)) I have this result : array (0) { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getItemMetaList() {
    var itemMetaArray = [];
    $('.frm_pro_form input, .frm_pro_form select, .frm_pro_form textarea').each(function(cpt){
        if($(this).attr('type') != 'hidden' && ($(this).attr("type") != "submit")) {
            itemMetaArray.push($(this).attr("name"));
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: "some.php",
       //data: { array: itemMetaArray}
       data: JSON.stringify({ array: itemMetaArray})
    }).done(function( msg ) {
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
}
```

you can send data by this way in a php file like documented here: [ajax jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

Comment: This is what I've done, thanks for the answer. But now the only problem is to get the array in PHP. For now the only things I've done is to display the content of the array in a <p> with this " success: function(){
                $('.answer').html(itemMetaArray);
            }" but I can't get the array data in a PHP variable.. My webpage isn't reload

Comment: i edited data in my code, it's an other way to send data. if it does not work like you want look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax

Comment: I already read this topic, but without a good solution. In my network tab I can see the POST request, with the content of the itemMetaArray. But the var_dump($_POST) still return an empty array...

Comment: it's a quite stange , i never get this kind of problem, can you post what you have in the network tab ? the content of itemMetaArray

Comment: Here is the picture : http://imgur.com/a/30Klz
Here is my .php : 
timgu
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/wordpress/script.js"></script>
<?php
echo "<script>getItemMetaList()</script>";
?>
<p class="answer"><?php print_r($_POST);?></p>

Comment: remove all except <?php var_dump($_POST); ?> in the index.php . if it return nothing or just an empty array , i can't help you more sorry

Comment: just one other thing : your itemMetaArray get a wrong format in the picture

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131038/discussion-between-nathan30-and-macbooc).

Answer (score 1):

The Ajax request returns data for JavaScript in the page loaded in your browser. The browser does not display the data automatically. The answer is captured by .done() in MacBook's example. You can put JavaScript in the done () method to display the data returned. If you wish the page to reload in your browser, Ajax is not the good way. In JavaScript, use form.submit instead. Then you can have your PHP code read the submitted data and generate a new html page and have this displayed by the browser.

Comment: Yes you're right, I saw in the "network" tab of Developper console that the "response" sub panel shows the array returned, while I see an empty array in the page