# Trying to use the javascript variabe as php variable and store it in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, api

I have two `JS` variables I want to use them as php variables and store them in the database.
Here is sample

```
var apiKey = 'apikey';
var pageToken = '';
var numOfResult = 0;
var maxResults = 200;
function searchVideo(){
   var separator = ",";
   $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&pageToken=' + pageToken + '&playlistId=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-&key=apikey&callback=?',function(data){
        var l = data.items.length;
        pageToken = data.nextPageToken;
        numOfResult += l;
        var itemUrl = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                if( i == 0) {
                        separator = ',';
                }
                else {
                        separator = ',';
                }
                var videoid = data.items[i].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                var title = data.items[i].snippet.title;
                console.log(videoid);

        }

        if( numOfResult < maxResults) {
                searchVideo();
        }

    });
}
```

How can I store variables `title` and `videoid` into the database using php mysql

Comment: You can use [`ajax`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php) for that

Comment: I dont have much idea about that and data is in loop is it possible to use that

Comment: [You can pass array to ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax). Store what you need to store in an array and pass that array

Comment: am unable to get how to use can you give me some help pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ajax` for this, here is how that would work.

1. Create an endpoint in PHP where you will accept this data via POST and insert it into DB.
2. Send an ajax request from JS to that endpoint to store data into the DB.

So, if the php endpoint for example is `add.php`, then Ajax code will look something like this(this is just an example, look into [`AJAX`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for better understanding):

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url:    "add.php",
  data: { title: title, videoid: videoid }
})
.done(function(data) {
  alert( "Data Saved");
});
```

Comment: by Using [`POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: yes am using post but how can i print the title and videoid to save them using mysql php

Comment: The same way you would if the data was coming from a form instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add value in the input hidden field and his name will be separate by name key and value.Hidden field be append in the form using any tag, id or class.I have used form tag here. You can submit that form and get all data in php POST variable. See below code snippet:

```
var apiKey = 'apikey';
var pageToken = '';
var numOfResult = 0;
var maxResults = 200;
function searchVideo(){
         var separator = ",";
         $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&pageToken=' + pageToken + '&playlistId=PLrEnWoR732-BHrPp_Pm8_VleD68f9s14-&key=apikey&callback=?',function(data){

                var l = data.items.length;
                pageToken = data.nextPageToken;
                numOfResult += l;
                var itemUrl = '';
                for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                        if( i == 0) {
                                separator = ',';
                        }
                        else {
                                separator = ',';
                        }
                        var videoid = data.items[i].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
                        var title = data.items[i].snippet.title;
                        console.log(videoid);

                        var input_data = "<input type='hidden' value='" + videoid + "' name='videoid[" + i + "]'><input type='hidden' value='" + title + "' name='title[" + i + "]'>";
                        $("form").append(input_data);

                }

                if( numOfResult < maxResults) {
                        searchVideo();
                }
        });
}
```

Comment: This code contains a cross-site-scripting (XSS) vulnerability

Comment: Yes it is just a workaround to the solution needed. One needs to apply security steps to prevent any injection/attack at browser/server level while processing form.