# Submit Array from view to controller using ajax (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, codeigniter, controller

I'm very new in web programming, especially on Codeigniter. And now I'm looking for  how to pass/submit array from view to controller.

This part of my HTML script in view:

```
<tr class="rowdim"> <!-- ROW 1 -->
<td><input type="text"  id="bookid1" name="book_id[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text"  id="qty1" name="qty[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text"  id="uom1" name="uom_id[]" /></td>
</tr>

<tr class="rowdim"> <!-- ROW 2 -->
<td><input type="text"  id="bookid2" name="book_id[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text"  id="qty2" name="qty[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text"  id="uom2" name="uom_id[]" /></td>
</tr>

<tr class="rowdim"> <!-- ROW 3 -->
<td><input type="text"  id="bookid3" name="book_id[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text"  id="qty3" name="qty[]" /></td>
<td><input type="text"  id="uom3" name="uom_id[]" /></td>
</tr>
```

My ajax:

```
var det_book = document.getElementsByName("book_id[]");
var det_qty = document.getElementsByName("qty[]");
var det_uom = document.getElementsByName("uom_id[]");
var vdata = {det_book:det_book,det_qty:det_qty,det_uom:det_uom}
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>trans/StockIn/saveData",
    data:vdata,
    success:function(returnmsg){
        if (returnmsg=='""'){
             window.alert(msg);
         } else {
             window.alert(returnmsg);
         }
});
```

Controller:

```
 $det_book=$_POST["det_book"];
 $det_qty=$_POST["det_qty"];
 $det_uom=$_POST["det_uom"];
 $details = array();
 $index=0;
 foreach ($det_book as $baris){
 array_push($details,array(
    'book_id'=>$baris,
    'quantity'=>$det_qty[$index],
    'uom_id'=>$det_uom[$index]
));
$index++; }
$error="";
if (!$this->db->insert_batch('trx_inbound_detail',$details))
{
    $error = $this->db->error();
}
```

Any miss or something wrong with my code? 
Already search in community but still no luck.
Appreciate if you also suggest other ways.
Thanks

Comment: Replace `var det_uom = document.getElementsByName("uom_id[]");` with `var det_uom = document.getElementsByName("uom[]");`

Comment: Edited. Passing done, controller still got issue.

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: trans/StockIn.php

Line Number: 98

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\penerbit\application\controllers\trans\StockIn.php
Line: 98
Function: _error_handler

Comment: Did you check with the browser's dev tools or the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Your first mistake is get the textbox value in multiple fields:

    var det_book = $('input[name^=book_id]').map(function(idx, elem) {
        return $(elem).val();
    }).get();

    var det_qty = $('input[name^=qty]').map(function(idx, elem) {
        return $(elem).val();
    }).get();

    var det_uom = $('input[name^=uom_id]').map(function(idx, elem) {
        return $(elem).val();
    }).get();
```

In php you didnot mention the index in foreach:

```
    foreach ($det_book as $index => $baris) {
         array_push($details,array(
            'book_id'=>$baris,
            'quantity'=>$det_qty[$index],
            'uom_id'=>$det_uom[$index]
        ));
    }

    print_r($details);
    exit();
```

Comment: Yes, actually I don't understand to get the `textbox` in multiple fields.
Using your method, it's work.
Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you missed something.
Element with name `book_id[]` doesn't exist. Also you have three inputs with same name.
Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax) to see how to pass array with ajax.

Comment: edited, but looked like the error comes from controller, in **foreach** part

Comment: Check for errors from JS side, if JS is okey then problem is with PHP.

Comment: Just found the problem is in this part:
    `var det_book = document.getElementsByName("book_id[]")`
capturing array data in JS from the input name. because when i try hardcode the array, everything's going fine.

Any idea?

Comment: @HooHoo Remove `[]` from `name` tag. Btw. what console(in browser) says

Comment: It says 
`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Object.toString (<anonymous>)`

Still same error even I remove the bracket `[]` from name tag