# How to pass array to ajax call in data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, object

I would like to know how to pass array of datas to ajax call
how to load modal until the data received in success in ajax.
Please check the below code and help.thanks

```
static(){
    var src = "SG";
    var tar = "TH";
    var samount = 1000;
    var sourceccy = "SGD";
    var targetccy = "THB";
    var providers = ["trans","fund"];
    $.ajax({
      url: "/en/send-money-from-" + sourcecn + "-to-" + targetcn,
      method: 'get',
      data: {
        srccn: src,
        tarcn: tar,
        source: sourceccy,
        target: targetccy,
        provider: providers //pass array in ajax call
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $('body').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass array to ajax request in $.ajax()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Comment: any chance you could restrict it to a single question (like what modal are you talking about, since you do a `console.log` you know where it will end up :)

Comment: @Icepickle thanks for reply, updated code

Answer (score 0):

Create an object like:

```
var obj = {
        "srccn": src,
        "tarcn": tar,
        "source": sourceccy,
        "target": targetccy,
        "provider": providers
      }
```

then in data use `data: JSON.stringify(obj);`