# how to jquery post array

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, post

I want to send this post
 using jquery with function post
my code is

```
{
 "version": "1.0",
 "method": "add",

 "pa[]": array["d11b41e7e9f0", array[
    "idC": 3105,
    "count": 150,
    "availability": 2
 ], "sendT", "a55d587068"],

 "id": 359
}
```

how to convert code to send

```
$.post("urlsite",ArrayData, function(data) { alert('done')  });
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(ArrayData)` just wrap your data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass array to ajax request in $.ajax()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax)

Comment: No clear indication of what `ArrayData` is and how it compares with your data, but no need to stringify if your back end is accepting form data.