# Parse numbers in jQuery.serializeArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm serializing a form as follows (inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11376215/2483127)):

```
function formToArray(jQueryObj){
var result = {};
var arr = jQueryObj.serializeArray();
$.each(arr, function(){
    result[this.name] = this.value;
});
return result;
}
```

This returns an object such as `{"input1_name":"value1", "input2_name": "42"}`. However, some of the inputs are numeric, and I want them to return numbers instead of strings. So my desired output is `{"input1_name":"value1", "input2_name": 42}`, the number not in quotes.

How can I achieve this with jQuery/JavaScript?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert the string back into a number you can use `Number()`:

```
$.each(arr, function(){
  if (!isNaN(this.value)) { //check if value is convertible to number
    result[this.name] = Number(this.value);
  } else {
    result[this.name] = this.value;
  }
});
```

Comment: Found a bug, when this.value === '0', the condition is false

Answer (score 1):

You can manually check if the value is number.

```
$.each(arr, function(){
  if (!isNaN(this.value)) { //Check for non numbers negation
    result[this.name] = Number(this.value);
  } else {
    result[this.name] = this.value;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the value and check it with isNaN

```
function formToArray(jQueryObj){
var result = {};
var arr = jQueryObj.serializeArray();
$.each(arr, function(){
   result[this.name] =isNaN(parseInt(this.value))?this.value:parseInt(this.value);
});
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var result = { };
$.each($('form').serializeArray(), function() {
    result[this.name] = Number(this.value) ? Number(this.value) : this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `"string" * 1` to coerce to a number

it's faster than using `Number` and `parseInt`
also, if you use `parseInt` remember to pass the radix 10 `parseInt(number, 10)`

```
var converted = this.value*1;
result[this.name] = isNaN(converted) ? this.value : converted;
```