# How to serialize a form in custom key/value pairs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to serialize a form in a *custom* key/value pair format. This is how my HTML code looks like:

```html
<form name="ltq_frm" id="ltq_frm">
  <table class="table" id="licenses_to_quote">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>License ID</th>
        <th>Quote ID</th>
        <th>Agreement Type</th>
        <th>Customer Site</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="licenses_to_quote_body">
      <tr data-id="96">
        <td>
          96
          <input type="hidden" name="license_id" value="96">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="hidden-select2-96" type="hidden" name="quote_id" value="249"> 249
        </td>
        <td>Percentage Support</td>
        <td>Frito-Lay, Inc.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-id="100">
        <td>
          100
          <input type="hidden" name="license_id" value="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="hidden-select2-100" type="hidden" name="quote_id" value="">
        </td>
        <td>Percentage Support</td>
        <td>Frito-Lay, Inc.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>

<button id="subm">
  Click
</button>
```

And this is how I am serializing it:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#subm').click(function() {
    var sA = $('#ltq_frm').serializeArray();
    var s = $('#ltq_frm').serialize();

    console.log(sA);
    console.log(s);
  });
});
```

This is "working" but I am getting an array of four values as output. I would like to get something like:

```
[
    'license_id' => 'quote_id'
]
```

Using the example above:

```
[
    96  => 249,
    100 => 
]
```

The values above comes from the hidden elements on the form, those named as `license_id` and `quote_id`.

I was checking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376184/jquery-serializearray-key-value-pairs) but I couldn't get the idea in how to transform my values into the needed key/value pairs.

[This is](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/kehxzq1L/1/) a jsFiddle I was working with in case you need it.

> Note: this is a code in development so if you have a better suggestion or need to give me something different go ahead

Comment: I think you'd have to tell us where these values are supposed to come from. You want `96 => 249`, but `96` is in a data attribute, in a value and in part of a classname, does it matter where this value is gotten from etc?

Comment: So like this then -> https://jsfiddle.net/kehxzq1L/3/

Comment: @adeneo yes sir, please add an answer as well I'll give you a vote ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually map each row, get the two inputs, use the first as the key and the second as the value, like this

```
var result = $('#ltq_frm tbody tr').map(function() {
    var inp = $('input', this), o   = {};

    o[inp.first().val()] = inp.last().val();
    return o;
}).get();
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/kehxzq1L/4/)

Answer (score 1):

I get it. You need a custom code like this to do it:

```
var finalObj = { };
$.each(​$('form')​.serializeArray()​, function() {
    finalObj[this.name] = this.value;
})​;

console.log(finalObj);
```

**Snippet**

```js
var finalObj = { };
$.each($('form').serializeArray(), function() {
  finalObj[this.name] = this.value;
});

console.log(finalObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="ltq_frm" id="ltq_frm">
  <table class="table" id="licenses_to_quote">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>License ID</th>
        <th>Quote ID</th>
        <th>Agreement Type</th>
        <th>Customer Site</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="licenses_to_quote_body">
      <tr data-id="96">
        <td>
          96
          <input type="hidden" name="license_id" value="96">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="hidden-select2-96" type="hidden" name="quote_id" value="249"> 249
        </td>
        <td>Percentage Support</td>
        <td>Frito-Lay, Inc.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-id="100">
        <td>
          100
          <input type="hidden" name="license_id[]" value="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="hidden-select2-100" type="hidden" name="quote_id[]" value="">
        </td>
        <td>Percentage Support</td>
        <td>Frito-Lay, Inc.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

**Update:** To get your custom way, I need to still change it further. In your question, the code has some inconsistencies. Those I corrected are as follows:

- `license_id[]` to `license_id`.
- `quote_id[]` to `quote_id`.

Please follow one single convention.

```js
var finalObj = { };
var lastLID = "";
$.each($('form').serializeArray(), function() {
  if (this.name == "license_id")
    lastLID = this.value;
  else (this.name == "quote_id")
    finalObj[lastLID] = this.value;
});

console.log(finalObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="ltq_frm" id="ltq_frm">
  <table class="table" id="licenses_to_quote">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>License ID</th>
        <th>Quote ID</th>
        <th>Agreement Type</th>
        <th>Customer Site</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="licenses_to_quote_body">
      <tr data-id="96">
        <td>
          96
          <input type="hidden" name="license_id" value="96">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="hidden-select2-96" type="hidden" name="quote_id" value="249"> 249
        </td>
        <td>Percentage Support</td>
        <td>Frito-Lay, Inc.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-id="100">
        <td>
          100
          <input type="hidden" name="license_id" value="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="hidden-select2-100" type="hidden" name="quote_id" value="">
        </td>
        <td>Percentage Support</td>
        <td>Frito-Lay, Inc.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: That's not what I am looking for, take a look at the example where the key `license_id` becomes the value of `name="license_id"` and the value `quote_id` becomes the value of `name="quote_id"`. Is this clear?

Comment: @ReynierPM I understood already. Check the updated answer please. You got what you wanted.

Comment: @ReynierPM Any reason you accepted the new answer? Just curious bro. `:)` Just curious coz the other answer gives in a different format than you expected, mine gives you the same format as you asked.

Comment: The answer above looks cleaner and it does return what I need, in fact is the one I am using, I give you the votes :)

Comment: Don't worry yours is useful as well I am pretty sure it'll work for anyone as well ;)

Comment: @ReynierPM Gotcha bro... Just was curious... `:)`